# Why is every monomial order a well-ordering?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, order-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative, unital ring. [According to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order), a *monomial order* is a total order $\leq$ on the space of monomials of a given polynomial ring of $R$ such that

1. If $u\leq v$ and $w$ is some monomial, then $uw\leq vw$;
2. $1\leq u$ for all $u$.

It is stated that monomial orders are well-orderings. This is not clear at all to me. I googled it but I couldn't find anything proving this. However, there are several places (lecture notes, mostly) where a monomial order is *defined* as a well-ordering in monomials respecting multiplication.

I am looking for a proof, or at least a reference for this fact?

Comment: Maybe $R$ is a polynomial ring over a field.

Comment: This follows (nonconstructively) from Dickson's lemma.